# Sample 'randomly' but ensure final sample representative of population?

Tags: r

I'm generating a chart with randomly selected images in a grid, like a mosaic.

When selecting from the 14 images like so `sample(1:14, 56, T)`, it would be idea if the sampling was random (as it is), but also had a constraint that *forced* it to ensure equal representation of each of the 14 images.

Is there a function that does this?

#### What I know so far

`sample()` has a `prob` parameter

> a vector of probability weights for obtaining the elements of the vector being sampled.

i.e. `sample(1:14, 1, T, prob=c(rep(1/14, 14)))`

But while this assigns equal probabilities (1/14 for each of the 14 elements), it ***doesn't*** enforce equal representation

Comment: An accept/reject Monte Carlo procedure like simulated annealing (aka Metropolis algorithm) would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating copies of all 14 image indices `rep(1:14, 4)` and then shuffle that array: `sample(rep(1:14, 4))`.

Comment: This is a strict enforcing that there is equal representation. If you want to assume equal samping probabilities instead, then what you had done earlier would work...